# ¿Si creo una Clase con un método virtual en C++, todas las subclases que la hereden deben implementar el método o puede haber alguna que no?

Tags: c++, poo, objeto, clase, clase-abstracta

No hay código, es una duda que tengo y no estoy pudiendo encontrar una respuesta, no se si al ser un método puro estoy obligado a implementarlo en todas las subclases y si no fuese puro no, o no tiene nada que ver y estoy obligado en ambos casos.

Comment: SI es virtual puro, si, las clases que la hereden tienen que implementarlo. Si no, no.

Comment: Por que mejor no haces la prueba, si quieres aprender algo tienes que descubrirlo

Answer (score 3):

La herencia de funciones miembro en C++ funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
#define CHIVATO std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct Base
{
    void Miembro() { CHIVATO; }
    virtual void Virtual() { CHIVATO; }
    virtual void VirtualPura() = 0;
};

struct Derivada : public Base
{
    void Miembro() { CHIVATO; }
    void Virtual() { CHIVATO; }
    void VirtualPura() { CHIVATO; }
};

int main()
{
    Derivada d;
    Base &b = d;

    b.Miembro();        // Muestra: Base::Miembro()
    b.Virtual();        // Muestra: Derivada::Virtual()
    b.VirtualPura();    // Muestra: Derivada::VirtualPura()

    d.Miembro();        // Muestra: Derivada::Miembro()
    d.Virtual();        // Muestra: Derivada::Virtual()
    d.VirtualPura();    // Muestra: Derivada::VirtualPura()

    return 0;
}
```

La función `Miembro` está presente en la base y en la derivada, si la llamo desde una base se llama la versión de `Base` y si la llamo desde la derivada se llama la versión de `Derivada`, es decir: la función es diferente en una y otra pese a que se llame igual; en cambio al llamar a las funciones `Virtual` y `VirtualPura` tanto si las llamo desde una base como si las llamo desde una derivada se llama la versión `Derivada`<sup>1</sup>.

Para verificar eso podemos añadir la palabra clave `override` y veremos lo siguiente:

```
struct Derivada : public Base
{
    void Miembro() override { CHIVATO; }        /* Error: Derivada::Miembro no 
                                                sobrescribe Base::Miembro */
    void Virtual() override { CHIVATO; }        // Correcto
    void VirtualPura() override { CHIVATO; }    // Correcto
};
```

Por último, veamos tu duda concreta:

```
struct Base
{
    void Publica() { CHIVATO; }
    void Miembro() { CHIVATO; }
    virtual void Virtual() { CHIVATO; }
    virtual void VirtualPura() = 0;
protected:
    void Protegida() { CHIVATO; }
protected:
    void Privada() { CHIVATO; }
};

struct Derivada : public Base
{
    void Miembro() { CHIVATO; }
    void Virtual() override { CHIVATO; }
    void VirtualPura() override { CHIVATO; }
};
```

La clase `Derivada` no ha necesitado implementar `Base::Publica`, ni `Base::Protegida` ni `Base::Privada`, sin embargo todas esas funciones han llegado a la instancia de `Derivada` (aunque sólo sean accesibles las públicas y protegidas).

La única función que es obligatorio implementar en todas las clases derivadas es `Base::VirtualPura`, si no la implementases en las derivadas y quisieras instanciarlas, fallaría la compilación.

---

<sup>1</sup>Porque en ambos casos la **instancia** es de `Derivada` aunque acceda a las funciones desde una referencia a `Base`.